# Разграничение прав юзерам в админке

Tags: права, php, mysql

Всем привет!

Знаю, что тема уже обсосана\пересосана, но каких-то отличных решений найти не смог, а писать с нуля, не имея опыта в данном деле достаточно опасно и сложно.

**Задача**

- разграничение прав у групп
- индивидуальное разграничение прав у юзера
- доступ к различным страницам и функциям на них

**Что есть?**

- сайт, написанный Без ООП, МVС и т.д...
- доступ в админку регулируется через htaccess

Из найденного очень понравился функционал http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/a-better-login-system/

Я да же поковырял скрипт, уменьшил количество запросов при проверке прав.
Но я не профи, чтобы оценить систему в целом. Аналогов не нашел(может плохо искал) готовых вообще.

Может кто-то использовал данную систему или знает хорошие, не сложные аналоги?
Под не сложными я понимаю:

1 - Удобную проверку типа

```
if (hasPerm('add_news'))
   echo 'Можно постить новости';
else
   echo 'Не дорос еще!';
```

2 - Поддержка как прав для групп, так и индивидуально.

Буду благодарен за советы и помощь

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто же. Сооружаем таблицу вида `id_юзера|id_действия`, протягиваем её между юзерами и действиями. При попытке совершить действие делаем выборку и смотрим, есть для данного действия и юзера запись - значит, можно. С группами аналогично.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Но могу что-то упустить при реализации, по тому, что только учусь, по этому искал готовые варианты.

А что можете сказать по той системе, что указал выше?